# Magento 2 braintree payment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, braintree

Braintree is slowing my website when "proceed to Checkout". But when changing to sandbox website is working good, but I have no idea why?

Need help!

Magento 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

In Sandbox testing, you are using dummy data to proceed with payment, Where in live. Actual credentials are processing, where card data are rendering from the respective card providers payment kits. so it actually takes time to process by default.